# wso2 - kerberose I get kinit: Client 'cbsrv@WSO2.ORG' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials "

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm working on my graduation project and am using wso2 identity server version ( 5.1 & 5.2 ) trough it to authenticate my service providers by kerberos authentication protocol, I follow this link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Kerberos+Security

I don't get ticket when enter kinit for users that already exist in wso2 identity server and I got this message:

> kinit: Client 'cbsrv@WSO2.ORG' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials

but when am using the wso2 identity server version 3.2, I get ticket and I can enter password for it, by follows this link: 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/

Answer (score 1):

1 - By using Ldap administration tools just make sure that the krb5PrincipalName is correct for your user (cbsrv)

2- When you add a new user using WSO2 Admin dashboard, WSO2 will store the client Principal in the following format

```
xxxx_carbon.super@WSO2.ORG
```

krb5PrincipalName  cbsrv_carbon.super@WSO2.ORG

if you modify this entry to 
cbsrv@WSO2.ORG using Ldap Admin tool then the Kinit cbsrv@WSO2.ORG will work fine for you.